# Is it a good idea to keep data in strings.xml?

Tags: android

Facebook in their [user guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) suggest to keep a `key` in `values/strings.xml` file. Have never seen such an approach before and it sounds odd for me. Is it something everybody use? I always thought is it better to keep such a data in config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly alright to keep data like this in `strings.xml`. Make sure you keep it in the default `/res/values/strings.xml` and not in any other `values` folder which has qualifiers attached to it. It may not be available on all devices if you do that.

Keeping this kind of data in config files is also perfectly acceptable (and the one I personally use, more because I find it easier to edit a Java file with static variables than an XML file in Eclipse).

Keeping the data in `strings.xml` means having an additional step in accessing it, as you'll need to get it from the resources using an instance of `Context`. Putting it as a static field in a Java class will make it slightly easier to access.

Both methods work fine, and are used commonly. It is really upto your personal preferences to pick one.

Comment: I would like to extend on the good answer Raghav gave by suggesting that you can also put it in a different file name, for example `/res/values/keys.xml`. That way you can keep user-visible strings in the strings.xml and keys on a separate file, making everything nice and organised.

Comment: +1 for `/res/values/keys.xml`. It makes also easy to create a system (for instance, using Maven) to automatically replace development keys with release keys during release phase.